# Simple html DOM parser get html tag

Tags: html, url, dom, hyperlink

I already waste 1 day with my try to get some links from HTML page by PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

My HTML code is:

```
<video id="videoPlayer1_lbp" width="660" height="281" preload="none" controls  poster="http://img.csfd.cz/files/images/film/video/preview/130/248/130248604_2a3904.jpg?h360"  style="display: none">
                    <source src="http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/360.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="846" height="360" />
                    <source src="http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/720.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1694" height="720" />
                    <source src="http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/360.webm" type="video/webm" width="846" height="360" />
                    <source src="http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/720.webm" type="video/webm" width="1694" height="720" />
                            <track src="/subtitles-proxy/?url=http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/cz.srt" type="text/x-srt" kind="subtitles" srclang="cz" label="cz"></track>
                </video>
```

What I want to get from this :

- Correct link on .MP4 file  correct link on .SRT file

I try tons of things, my last try is this:

```
foreach ( $html->find('video source') as $element ) {
    echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```

Can somebody help me with that to make it work?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For video files:

```
foreach($html->find('source') as $e) 
    if($e->type =='video/mp4')  {

        echo $e->src. '<br>';

    }
```

.srt file:

```
foreach($html->find('track') as $e) 
    echo $e->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: Be sure to click the check mark so it is marked as the Accepted answer.